# How to recover "pretty" format after split?

Tags: output-formatting

I'm doing this:

[image]

And get this:

[image]

But what I wanted is:

[image]

How can I get the desired output? Is there a way to recover the format from the cryptic output?

Note: my "real" list is way longer than just two terms and I want to keep the "pretty" format in order to show the output.

Comment: This isn't general enough but maybe good enough for you so: `ToString[#, StandardForm] & /@ 
   ToExpression[
    "{" <> # <> 
     "}"] &@myString`

Comment: If you do `FullForm` on your string you will see the underlying plain text string contains several commas. `StringSplit` splits on those and so the result would be pretty hard to undo.

Comment: Please post properly-formatted, copy-and-paste-able *Mathematica* code rather than screenshots of your code. It's nice to be able to just copy and paste code into our own copies of *Mathematica* instead of re-typing expressions the OP has already written.

Comment: @george2079, OK, but how can I get the result? Maybe with another approach

Comment: @xndrme Try the code from my comment.

Comment: @Kubas approach is best. Just for completness you can reassemble your formatted strings with care: `(StringJoin[Riffle[#, ","]] & /@ Partition[StringSplit[#, ","], 2]) &@mystring`.  This is specialized to the case where each term has *exactly* one comma in its FullForm string.

Comment: @Kuba your solution is working but not well enough, the problem is that X_u has an assigned value. Thus what I get is something like {"{-v Sin[u], v Cos[u], a}",...

Comment: @george2079 It seens to be the correct solution, at least is working for me

Comment: @march If you can show me how to show X_u with the pretty format by just copying the code I'll be glad to post a copy-paste version.

Comment: @xndrme. In general, that comment I left is for the future: in this particular case, the code is simple enough that it's not really a problem. That said, if you had copied and pasted, you would've have seen that the subscripted symbol would paste as `Subscript[X, y]` or as a long mess of `SubscriptBox`'s and `\`'s (depending on how you copy and past), which would actually have shown you immediately what the problem is. That's sort of the point. (It's still a good question, though, because this stuff is not obvious.)

Comment: @march OK, fair enough for me, I'm still learning the way of Mathematica.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This might work for you. The idea is to create a `PatternTest` function which only returns `True` outside of box structures.

```
mysplit[s_String, c_String] := Module[{f, i = 0},
  f["\("] := i++;
  f["\)"] := i--;
  f[c] := i == 0;
  StringSplit[s, _?f]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

a bit of an overkill answer:

start with a somewhat more involved example. The string is keyed in using `control-_` for subscripts etc.

[image]

> {"Y", "!(*SubscriptBox[(X)", " (u)])", \
>   "!(*SubscriptBox[(X)", " (p)])", "X", \
>   "!(*TagBox[SubsuperscriptBox[\"x\"", " \"0\"", " \"n\"]", "
>     DisplayForm])", "p"}

this is a mess because `StringSplit` has operated on all the commas embedded in the format code.

so.. reassemble by joining parts until they are valid strings. (see https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/102969/2079 )

```
validstring[s_String] := 
 Nand[StringMatchQ[s, ___ ~~ "\!\(" ~~ ___], ToString[s] === s ]
Reap[last = Fold[ If[validstring[#1], (Sow[#1]; #2),
      p = StringJoin[#1, ",", #2]] & , First@badsplit , 
    Rest@badsplit]; If[validstring[last], Sow[last]]][[2, 1]]
```

> [image]

Of course the best approach is to not use `StringSplit` in the first place.
( See comments )