# Importing CSV with multiline text fields

Tags: bugs, import, csv-format, data-acquisition, parsing

**Bug introduced in 8 or earlier and fixed in 11.2.0**

---

Here is a valid CSV:

```
a1,b1,c1,d1,"e1
e1
e1"
a2,b2,"c2
c2
c2",d2,e2
```

It has two rows and five columns, and contains two fields with embedded CRLF. (See the [CSV standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180)). But *Mathematica* doesn't parse it as such.

```
Import["test.csv", "CSV"]
```

Result:

```
{{"a1,b1,c1,d1,\"e1"}, {"e1"}, {"e1\""}, {"a2,b2,\"c2"}, {"c2"}, {"c2\"", "d2", "e2"}}
```

The result is the same if I use

```
Import["test.csv","CSV","TextDelimiters"->"\""]
```

How can I get *Mathematica* to parse the CSV correctly?

Comment: Try TSV? Often works when CSV breaks.

Comment: Duplicate WC thread: http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1159443

Answer (score 5):

Here is a code which accepts inside the fields delimited by double-quotes:

- commas
- carriage-returns
- any character different from double-quotes

This solution is not fully compliant with the [standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180), particularly with the point 6 of page 3, where it is written that a double-quotes may exist in a field.

This solution has not been tried on large files.

**Preliminary**

Generation of the file to import :

```
Export["file.txt", "a1,b1,c1,d1,\"e1
 e1
 e1\"
 a2,b2,\"c2
 c2
 c2\",d2,e2", "Text"]
```

Importation of the whole file as a single string:

```
text00 = Import["file.txt", "Text"]
```

Here is a utility for nice rendering of the CarriageReturn/Line-Feed (CRLF) :

```
toVisibleCRLF[exp_] := exp /. str_String :>  
        Row[StringSplit[str , "\n" -> Style["CRLF", Red]] ];
```

Test of the utility on the imported text :

```
toVisibleCRLF[text00]
```

[image]

**Parsing**

The idea is to isolate the  shortest pairs of quotes (1) by wrapping them in a inert structure called `doNotSplit[]` :

```
list00 = StringSplit[text00, str : Shortest["\"" ~~ ___ ~~ "\""] :> doNotSplit[str]];
list00 // toVisibleCRLF // Column
```

[image]

Then the proper substrings are splitted at the commas and carriage-return.
Commas are eliminated.
Carriage-returns are maintained because we will need them for further record separations:

```
list01 = Flatten[
   If[Head[#] =!= doNotSplit, 
      StringSplit[#, {",", "\n" -> "\n"}], #] & /@ list00];
list01 // toVisibleCRLF // Column
```

[image]

Next records are isolated:

```
list02 = Split[list01, And[#1 =!= "\n", #2 =!= "\n"] &];
list02 // toVisibleCRLF // (Grid[{#}] & /@ # &) // Column
```

[image]

The code `list02 = Split[list01, And[#1 =!= "\n", #2 =!= "\n"] &]` is equivalent to
`list02 = Split[list01, ! Or[#1 === "\n", #2 === "\n"] &]`. It has splitted the list before **and** after each `\n`. That's the simplest way the remove the `\n` afterwards.

The final result is obtained after removing of the `\n`  and the `doNotSplit` :

```
result = DeleteCases[list02 /. doNotSplit[str_] :> str, {"\n"}];
result // Grid
```

[image]

The whole useful code :

```
text00 = Import["file.txt", "Text"]; 
list00 = StringSplit[text00, 
   str : Shortest["\"" ~~ ___ ~~ "\""] :> doNotSplit[str]];
list01 = Flatten[
   If[Head[#] =!= doNotSplit, 
      StringSplit[#, {",", "\n" -> "\n"}], #] & /@ list00];
list02 = Split[list01, And[#1 =!= "\n", #2 =!= "\n"] &];
result = DeleteCases[list02 /. doNotSplit[str_] :> str, {"\n"}]
```

**Edit**

(1) "shortest" in the meaning of the `Shortest[]` of *Mathematica*, which is a little bit special. For example, the pattern `Shortest["A"~~__~~"B"]` assumes the whole text is read from left to right and it takes the text between the *first* "A" and the *next* "B".
Of course, if there are several sequences "A...B" *Mathematica* redo it again.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a start..

```
Export["test.txt", "a1,b1,c1,d1,\"e1\ne1\ne1\"\na2,b2,\"c2\nc2\nc2\",d2,e2"]

i = 0;
StringSplit[StringJoin[#], ","] & /@ 
  Split[Characters[Import["test.txt", "Text"]],
   (If[# == "\"", ++i]; ! (# == "\n" && EvenQ[i]) ) &]
```

Note this will break if there are commas within quoted strings.

Edit: a bit more elegant..and this takes care of the comma-within-quotes issue.

```
stringsplitnoquote[string_String, d_String /; StringLength[d] == 1] :=
  Module[{i = 1},
  StringSplit[
   string, _?((If[# == "\"", i *= -1]; i == 1 && # == d) &)]]

stringsplitnoquote[#, ","] & /@ 
     stringsplitnoquote[ Import["test.txt", "Text"] , "\n"]
```

Due credit.. borrowed from here : https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/103030/2079

Answer (score 1):

Explicit setting for the option `"LineSeparators"` solves the problem (checked with versions 8.0.4, 10.4.1 and 11.1.1):

```
ImportString["a1,b1,c1,d1,\"e1
e1
e1\"
a2,b2,\"c2
c2
c2\",d2,e2", "CSV", "LineSeparators" -> "\n"]
```

> ```
> {{"a1", "b1", "c1", "d1", "e1\ne1\ne1"}, 
>  {"a2", "b2", "c2\nc2\nc2", "d2", "e2"}}
> ```

Just released *Mathematica* 11.2.0 with updated CSV importer handles your example correctly by default:

```
$Version
ImportString["a1,b1,c1,d1,\"e1
e1
e1\"
a2,b2,\"c2
c2
c2\",d2,e2", "CSV"]
```

> ```
> "11.2.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (September 11, 2017)"
>
> {{"a1", "b1", "c1", "d1", "e1\ne1\ne1"}, 
>  {"a2", "b2", "c2\nc2\nc2", "d2", "e2"}}
> ```