# How to make Import[...., "Table"] not convert strings to numbers and not convert numbers to strings?

Tags: bugs, import, csv-format, data-acquisition

**Bug introduced in 8 or earlier and persisting through 11.2.0**

---

I have to to use `r = Import["foo.txt", "Table", "FieldSeparators" -> {","}]`  since my data is Table which is comma separated and it contains a mixture of strings and numerical data.  Here is an example of file, of two lines:

> ```
> 0,"a","0"
>
> 1,"c","xyz"
> ```

The problem is that

```
r = Import["foo.txt", "Table", "FieldSeparators" -> {","}]
```

will convert the field `"0"` to numeric `0` when imported. This causes me problems since that field can sometimes actually be a string (much longer than shown).

If I use

```
r = Import["foo.txt", "Table", "FieldSeparators" -> {","}, "Numeric" -> False]
```

Then all the fields are imported as `String`.

I looked and can't find an option to tell `Import` to please please just leave my data "is as" and just import it as it is on the file.

I could import everything as strings, and then convert those fields that I know should really be numerical (in this example, the fields in the first column), back to numerical after importing the data using a post-processing step, as last resource (using `ToExpression` applied to each field in each record which is meant to be numeric).

But thought to ask if there is an option I overlooked.  For reference

```
 ref/format/Table
```

Version 11.1

Comment: doesnt `Import[file,"CSV"]` do what you need?

Comment: @george2079 No, I need to keep the embeded string intacr. Hence the need to `"TextDelimiters" -> None` as given in answer.

Comment: Ok, I hadn't tried it. I think "csv" converting a deliberately quoted number is incorrect behavior as well.

Comment: The bug is still there in version 11.2.0. Reported as [CASE:3965884].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Diagnosis

According to the Documentation, the [`"Table"`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/Table.html) format (as well as [`"CSV"`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/CSV.html) and [`"TSV"`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/TSV.html))

> - Stores numerical and textual information, formatted as a table.

and for separating textual information from numerical in these data formats we have

> - `Import` and `Export` option:
>     
>     `"TextDelimiters"` `Automatic` string or list of strings used to delimit non-numeric fields

Based on this I consider the following behavior as a **bug**:

```
ImportString["0000123,\"0000123\"", "CSV", "TextDelimiters" -> "\""]
```

> ```
> {{123, 123}}
> ```

Below is what I would expect to get from `Import` according to the Docs and the common sense:

> ```
> {{123, "0000123"}}
> ```

Tracing the evaluation shows that `Import` removes the substrings specified via `"TextDelimiters"` *before* converting the fields which match (an analog of) `NumberString` into numbers. The correct implementation would be to remove the delimiters *after* converting numeric fields into numbers.

The Documentation statement

> - Double-quote characters delimiting text fields are not imported by default.

is in accord with my interpretation: with the option `"TextDelimiters" -> "\""` the textual field above should be imported as `"0000123"` (i.e. without the double-quotes inside of the string).

Current behavior of `"TextDelimiters" -> None` is correct – it imports all non-`NumberString` fields "as is":

```
ImportString["0000123,\"0000123\", Sin[x] ,'another field'", "CSV", 
 "TextDelimiters" -> None]
```

> ```
> {{123, "\"0000123\"", " Sin[x] ", "'another field'"}}
> ```

```
ImportString["0000123,\"0000123\", Sin[x] ,'another field'", "CSV", 
 "TextDelimiters" -> None, "Numeric" -> False]
```

> ```
> {{"0000123", "\"0000123\"", " Sin[x] ", "'another field'"}}
> ```

But the case of `"TextDelimiters" -> " "` demonstrates another bug:

```
ImportString["0000123,\"0000123\", Sin[x] ,'another field'", "CSV", 
 "TextDelimiters" -> " "]
```

> ```
> {{"0000123,\"0000123\", Sin[x] ,'another field'"}}
> ```

Below is what I would expect to obtain instead:

> ```
> {{123, "\"0000123\"", "Sin[x]", "'another field'"}}
> ```

---

### A workaround

A workaround is to use `"TextDelimiters" -> None` with postprocessing:

```
ImportString["0,\"a\",\"0\"
1,\"c\",\"xyz\"", "CSV", "TextDelimiters" -> None]
```

> ```
> {{0, "\"a\"", "\"0\""}, {1, "\"c\"", "\"xyz\""}}
> ```

```
% /. field_String :> 
  StringReplace[field, StartOfString ~~ "\"" ~~ s___ ~~ "\"" ~~ EndOfString :> s]
```

> ```
> {{0, "a", "0"}, {1, "c", "xyz"}}
> ```

The suggested approach works correctly in the general case:

```
ImportString["0000123,\"0000123\",Sin[x],'another field'", "CSV", 
  "TextDelimiters" -> None] /. 
 field_String :> 
  StringReplace[field, StartOfString ~~ "\"" ~~ s___ ~~ "\"" ~~ EndOfString :> s]
```

> ```
> {{123, "0000123", "Sin[x]", "'another field'"}}
> ```

---

P.S. Another shortcoming of the CSV importer which may be considered as a bug both in `"TextDelimiters"` and `"LineSeparators"`:

- [Importing CSV with multiline text fields](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/103498/28)

Comment: I am sorry, but how do I use `ImportString` to import the data from the file?

Comment: Just use `Import` with the same options.

Comment: What about `​\\​` character in the string? it seems to disappear when you make an expression out of it...

Comment: @Stitch, in Alexey's example, the backslash is intended to escape the `"` character (thus, `"\""`). A literal backslash in a string would look like `"\\"`.

Comment: @J.M. Do you agree that the described behavior contradicts the Docs? Is it a bug?

Comment: @J.M. I mean exactly the "\\", that is literally a single backslash in the file that gets imported as "\\", but then after expression, it is eliminated from the string. Try `ToExpression["\"ab \\ c\""]`, the result you get is simply `"ab  c"`

Comment: @Alexey, before that... have you seen the result of `ImportString["0000123,\"0000123\"", "CSV", "TextDelimiters" -> "\"\""]`?

Comment: @J.M. Thanks, now I see your point. We have to specify two delimiters as **one** string: `ImportString["0000123,\"0000123'", "CSV", "TextDelimiters" -> "\"'"]`. But it looks like another bug as well as the excessive `\"` in the imported textual fields.

Comment: @J.M. No, it just becomes equivalent to `"TextDelimiters" -> None` for this case what also looks as a bug.

Comment: Yes, it looks to be the same. It is unfortunate that the docs do not give a demonstration of how to properly set `"TextDelimiters"`, so it is hard to tell what is and what isn't buggy.

Comment: @J.M. There is the statement "`"TextDelimiters"-> "\""` puts double quotes around each text field when exporting to CSV." And also "With `"TextDelimiters"->{"<",">"}`, `Export` wraps text fields in angular brackets."

Comment: Right, the behavior for `Export[]`/`ExportString[]` seems self-evident; it's the importing that's confusing. I'm now reminded of something messy I needed to deal with years ago...

Comment: @Stitch I updated the answer with better post-processing method which will work correctly in the general case.