# Specify column data type when importing

Tags: import, string-manipulation, notation

I'm running into an annoying issue when importing a table of tab-separated-data. Several columns are numeric, while several are strings. Using `Import[url,"TSV"]` basically works perfectly - however, some of the strings are "5d2", "4e1" or things of that nature, which Import then interprets as scientific notation. For instance, `ImportString["4d2", "TSV"]` yields `{{400.}}`, which I do not want. However there are some columns which are properly in scientific notation (i.e. 2.3e+02) which I do want intepreted as numbers - is there a clean way to selectively import certain table columns as numbers, leaving others as strings?

Comment: You can use `ReadList` instead and specify columns' types: `ReadList["path to file here",{Word, Number}]` for a file with "4d2" in first column and 2.3e+02 in the second.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing more, I would first say to look at using the `"Numeric" -> False` option in

```
Import["data.tsv", "TSV", "Numeric" -> False]
```

This *seems* (I've never worked with this functionality until now and I got the idea from [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/140785/how-to-make-import-table-not-convert-strings-to-numbers-and-not-convert/140789).) to leave everything as strings.

This also takes care of the misinterpretation of scientific notation problem as

```
ImportString[#, "TSV", "Numeric" -> False] & /@ {"4e1", "5d2"}
InputForm@%
```

> {{{4e1}},{{5d2}}}
>
> {{{"4e1"}}, {{"5d2"}}}

Then, once everything is imported as strings, you can change the columns of scientific notation strings to numbers.  For example,

```
data[[;;, column]] = Internal`StringToDouble /@ data[[;;, column]]
```

(Also stole the `` Internal`StringToDouble `` from [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1737/how-do-you-convert-a-string-containing-a-number-in-c-scientific-notation-to-a-ma).)

All together

```
data = Import["data.tsv", "TSV", "Numeric" -> False]
data[[-1]] = Internal`StringToDouble /@ data[[-1]];
data
```

> {{"1"}, {"2"}, {"3"}, {"4"}, {"5"}, {"6"}, {"7"}, {"8"}, {"9"}, {"10"}, {"4e1"}, {"5d2"}, {"2.3e+02"}}
>
> {{"1"}, {"2"}, {"3"}, {"4"}, {"5"}, {"6"}, {"7"}, {"8"}, {"9"}, {"10"}, {"4e1"}, {"5d2"}, {230.}}

Answer (score 1):

If your file.tsv has data such as:

> "4d2" 2.3e+02 105.5
>
> "5e1" -1.3e05 235

Then [SemanticImport](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SemanticImport.html) may help:

```
data = SemanticImport["file.tsv",{"String","Number","Number"}, "HeaderLines"-> 0]
```

Set `HeaderLines` appropriately to reflect the presence of header row(s) in your file.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your file is like this (two different types of columns for simplicity):

```
"4d2"    2.3e+02
"5e1"    -1.3e-05
```

I use here `StringToStream` to simulate file, but you just place your file (path + name) instead (`ReadList["path to file",{Word, Number}]`) with appropriate number and types of columns you have:

```
ReadList[StringToStream["\"4d2\"\t2.3e+02\n\"5e1\"\t-1.3e-05"], {Word, Number}]
```

which gives

```
{{"4d2", 230.}, {"5e1", -0.000013}}
```