# regex to find \n within quotes and not ones outside quotes

Tags: regular-expressions

For example,

```
string = "ads, 32, dv, \"sdf\"
  sd, 213, as, \"asd
  asd\"
  asd, 123 sd, \"asd\"";
```

There are 3 line returns `\n`. I want to find the second one since it is inside the quotes (`""`).

```
StringCases[string,RegularExpression["put regular expression here"]];
```

I have tried the following regex which should work if only Mathematica would allow variable length lookbehind assertions:

```
RegularExpression["(?<=,\"[^\"]*)\\n(?=[^\"]*\",)"]
```

Comment: routes = quotes? Can you give *Mathematica* code to create the string you're actually providing in the question? Without that, it's ambiguous.

Comment: i have updated the code.

Comment: Sorry, I just saw now that i misspelled the word quote in the title.

Answer (score 3):

You are able to reference the parenthesised sections of your `RegularExpression` on the right-hand side with `RuleDelayed`.

With

```
string = "ads, 32, dv, \"sdf\"
  sd, 213, as, \"asd
  asd\"
  asd, 123 sd, \"asd\"";
```

Then

```
StringCases[
 string,
 RegularExpression["\"([^\"]+?\n[^\"]+?)\""] :> "$1"
 ]
```

> ```
> {"asd
> asd"}
> ```

Hope this helps.

Comment: A false match is found in the string `"1,\"abc\",3\n4,\"def\",6\n"`.

Comment: @WReach It returns `{",3\n4,"}` as expected (with *Mathematica* 8.0.4).

Comment: @Edmund Actually `Rule` works here as well as `RuleDelayed`.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov I was assuming that the usual rules for matching quotes were to be respected (e.g. like in CSV parsing).  Under that assumption, I expect no matches from my example.  Perhaps the OP can clarify whether quote matching is a requirement.

Comment: @WReach Thanks, added a special note to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution which won't include the outer quotes in the matched string and hence will count every quote *twice*:

```
StringCases["a\"b\nc\"d\ne\"", RegularExpression["(?<=\")[^\"]+?\n[^\"]+?(?=\")"]]
```

> ```
> {"b\nc", "d\ne"}
> ```

Compare to [Edmund](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/19542/edmund)'s [solution](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/149503/280):

```
StringCases["a\"b\nc\"d\ne\"", 
 RegularExpression["\"([^\"]+?\n[^\"]+?)\""] :> "$1"]
```

> ```
> {"b\nc"}
> ```

Note that both solutions use `+` instead of `*` since you wish to find only the second `\n` what contradicts the title of the question: "regex to find \n within quotes and not ones outside quotes". Based on the title only, the solution would use `*` in order to allow matching lonely newline character inside of the quotes:

```
StringCases[string, RegularExpression["(?<=\")[^\"]*?\n[^\"]*?(?=\")"]]
```

> ```
> {"\n  sd, 213, as, ", "asd\n  asd", "\n  asd, 123 sd, "}
> ```

It is worth to add also that both mine and [Edmund](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/19542/edmund)'s [solution](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/149503/280) completely ignore the usual rules for matching quotes as [WReach](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/142/wreach) correctly notes in the [comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/149481/regex-to-find-n-within-quotes-and-not-ones-outside-quotes/149503?noredirect=1#comment401110_149503). If quote matching is required, one should apply approaches shown in the following threads:

- [How to get the longest bracket pairs from a string](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/125391/280)
- [String matching balanced pairs of braces](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/87329/280)
- [Importing CSV with multiline text fields](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/103498/280)